# Resampling raster ignores small bits

Tags: r, terra

I have two `terra` rasters, which look like this when plotted on top of each other:

[image]

The fine raster has a resolution of 0.1m, the rough raster has a resolution of 0.5m. But when I resample the fine raster to the resolution of the rough raster, cells with only few pixels disappear:

[image]

Here is the code I used:

```
# plot raster
plot(fine, col = "red")
plot(rough, add = T)
  
# maximum resample
resampled <- resample(fine, rough, "max")

# plot raster
plot(resampled , col = "red")
```

Why is this happening? Can I prevent this somehow? I want the output to have cells wherever at least one cell of the fine raster is present.

Here my data:
https://github.com/zoeschindler/zoeschindler/blob/main/fine.tif
https://github.com/zoeschindler/zoeschindler/blob/main/rough.tif

Comment: You seem to be missing 4 px from your raster `resampled` because these cells are located outside of the bbox of `fine`, whereas the extent of `resampled` matches the one of `rough`. Same happens e.g. with `method="sum"`. I'd consider this partial exclusion to be a bug and file an issue.

Comment: I'm likely wrong, but perhaps you want `fine_agg2 <- aggregate(fine, fact=5, fun=max)
> res(fine_agg2)
[1] 0.5 0.5`, instead of resample. `res(rough) [1] 0.5 0.5`. Factor used was arrived at by 'fishing around'.

Comment: By now I actually resorted to modifying the extent using `extend()` and subsequently using `aggregate()` to get perfectly overlapping maximum cells. But this is still weird behaviour of `resample()`, isn't it?